# Section with background image expanding to overall sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently building a web page and encountered the following problem and would appreciate if someone helped me solve it:

I want to have a full-width background image for every "section" (div) of the page. Within this background, there is a smaller div for content (text). On the right, there is a scrolling sidebar which scrolls with the user. I could not find how to have a full-width div and the sidebar(which is a div element with descendants) going over it?

The current structure looks like:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      here go all the "sections"...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      and that is the sidebar...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So in short, what is needed is background images with some html content on top of them and a sidebar on the right (but being covered by the image). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the full code so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Thanks Dennis, this really is the code - I have not filled any content yet and cannot do so until a solution to this is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess that means you plan to make a fixed sidebar? You need to put the columns in a row. Make the row have the background-image. Position the sidebar fixed, this makes the bootstrap class ineffective but you can make the width 25% so it stays responsive. You may need to add some padding/margin, but I made something up quick with random colors so you can get the idea.

```css
#sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  width:25%;
  color:white;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
.white{
  background-color:white;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row red">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        Section 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar">
        and that is the sidebar...<br/>
        ber<br/>
        baer
        badsr
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row white">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        Section 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row blue">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        Section 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately if I use width: 25%; instead of bootstrap, then it does not remain responsive in that opening it on a small device will not render as a column below/above the main content. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, at a certain size, take off the position fixed. Change it to position relative. So for example, put the #sidebar{position:fixed; width:25%, top:0; right:0} in a media query with a min screen size of 992px; Then after that, it will go back into the flow of your content. If  you want the sidebar to go to the bottom of the screen in mobile, initially put the sidebar in the last section on your page. Otherwise, you can put it to the left of the col-md-9 in the first section to appear at the top.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much indeed! Can I make sure that the sidebar stays within the container? (i.e. does not overlap with the footer)

Comment: If you are doing a fixed sidebar, you would have to use some js to calculate if it was a certain height above the footer and stop it. You'd have to search to find out how, I don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div outside of your container class. That div can be set to a full width.

```
    <div class="row"> <!-- begins full width row-->

      <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-9">
             here go all the "sections"...
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
          and that is the sidebar...
         </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- ends full width row-->
```

Comment: But this will not stretch the background of each section to full screen width?